# how to suppress leftmost column (day) as it kept coming in my output as integer

Tags: r, apply

I have some data that currently try to run. The problem is the first column is day and described as integer. Thus when I apply for sum, the days are counted as well. How to suppress the problem?

```
medhist <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
 Day  CVS Respi DM  Epilepsy
    1   2    3     4    0
    2   3    2     2    2
    3   3    3     4    2 
    4   4    3     2    1
    5   1    3     1    3
    6   2    2     NA   3
    7   3    2     1    0
    8   2    3     2    0
    9   2    3     2    1
    10  2    4     5    1
 ')

apply(medhist, 2, sum, na.rm=T)
```

whereby the output is

```
     Day      CVS    Respi       DM Epilepsy 
      55       24       28       23       13
```

I have tried

```
medhist$Day<- as.character(medhist$Day)
```

as well as

```
medhist$Day<- as.factor(medhist$Day)
```

but it produces error for both codes that I tried

```
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

Comment: With the call to apply you compress each colum to one value. How do you want to compress the "day" column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you may want to concatenate the `length()` (i.e. count) of days with the intended summary without the `Day` column. Assuming the days are unique you may do this:

```
c(Day=length(medhist$Day), apply(medhist[-1], 2, sum, na.rm=TRUE))
# Day      CVS    Respi       DM Epilepsy 
#  10       24       28       23       13
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use `summarise_at` for the selected columns and then append the other column value of interest

```
library(dplyr)
medhist %>%
  summarise_at(-1, sum, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  bind_cols(Day = last(medhist$Day), .)
```